# transclusion and accessing parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to have a child directive that is transcluded by a parent directive that accesses the controller of the parent directive. But I get the error "Controller 'testParent', required by directive 'testChild', can't be found;"

```
app.directive('testParent', function(){
  return {
    restrict :'E',
    template: '<div>',
    transclude:true,
    controller: function(){
      this.log = function() {
        console.log('test');
      }
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, unusedController, transcludeFn) {
      element.append(transcludeFn());
    }
  }
});

app.directive('testChild', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template: '<div>Child</div>',
    require:'^testParent',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
      controller.log();
    }
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/miqH0r80G8bI0B5bAOzA?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append it to DOM by using `transcludeFn` cloned DOM

```
transcludeFn(function(clone) {
    element.append(clone);
});
```

[**Demo PLunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Du8Ad2oNjnhmlEpmNPo2?p=preview)